# Windows CE how to install to a Thin Client?

Tags: windows, embedded

I accidently bought a thin client without Windows CE (haven't clicked on a checkbox...)

Now I would like to know how to install Windows CE by myself.

( I want to install a trial version )

The thing client has built it Compact Flash drive with 512Mb capacity.
800Mhz CPU and 512Mb RAM.

I went to Microsoft.com and ordered an 180 day evaluation copy.

Right now the problem is with..the following. It's only 2 Mb exe file. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a downloader; I've pulled full Windows images from  the MSDNAA website before and they start out as about 2MB files.

Run the exe on a normal desktop PC with backups (just in case - I'd like to assume that they'd give you some kind of confirmation before doing something nasty to your system).  That is likely to produce an image that you can use to boot your thin client.

Note that I've never used Windows CE before, this is just how it works with the other OSes that I've gotten from Microsoft.